# Different IPv4 numbers if I search on google.com or google.com.bo

Tags: networking, ip

If I search on **google.com** the words "my ip", Google returns an IP number that belongs to my ISP:

```
About 447,000,000 results (0.46 seconds) 

200.x.x.x
Your public IP address
```

But, if I made the same search ("my ip"), on the same computer at the same time, but on **google.com.bo**, it returns an IP from a different company from my country:

```
About 447,000,000 results (0.46 seconds) 

181.x.x.x
Your public IP address
```

I checked twice, and I don't have configured any proxy or VPN on the browsers or my computer.

What could be the explanation? It seems like my ISP is doing a load balancing as @acejavelin said, but based on what? DNS?

**EDIT: I removed all the useless information and leave only the important**. If I made a mistake, I can restore the question as it was before.

Comment: that is interesting, the same thing happened on my system.

Comment: It sounds like one of your browsers is configured to use a proxy.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion but I know nothing of the sort is going on in my system.

Comment: I updated my question. whatsmyipaddress.com returns what would be the right IP number, the one that belongs to my ISP. Google on Firefox does the same, but Google on Chrome, no. This is very weird.

Comment: Can you post a traceroute to the erroneous IP? You can obfuscate the first and last hops if you want.

Comment: Done. Meanwhile, this is really weird. Amazon detects that my IP number is 181.x.x.x. The wrong one!

Comment: Can you post the actual incorrect IP?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not a corporate network environment (that would off topic), the most likely case since your ISP is handing you an address in private IP space (172.31.x.x) is it has multiple public IPs that are both 200.x.x.x and 181.x.x.x and it using some kind of load balancing algorithm/device, causing some connections to the outside world to take path (200.x.x.x IP address) and other times or destinations it takes a different path (181.x.x.x IP address) and it seen as those corresponding addresses on the far end. This is not uncommon and often cannot be replicated since even connections to the same host may cause a different public IP address to be seen due to the variable nature load balancing can do since it could be based on traffic, time of day, destination, distribution of traffic and other details. If you are concerned, I would contact your ISP and ask them if this is normal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already contact my ISP, but as always, they are going "to call me back as soon as possible". That means that they are going to call me on Monday :-/  Anyway, I would like to confirm this. It's very possible.

Comment: please check my last update, 6. What do you think?